# Ajax.Updater and python response to request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, python-2.7, prototypejs

I have a python code which generates a HTML page using a template. When a click event occurs, I need to read an Excel file and display some results, probably in a pop-up. I thought I could read the Excel file using `xlrd`. I could use an `ajax request` to give the `url` of the python file that reads the excel file. I decided to use `Prototype`'s `Ajax.Updater` for this.

Ajax.Updater is supposed to replace the `response` item with the response from python file `display.py`.

I have two questions-

1. how do we send the response back from python? This is probably a trivial question but i couldn't find anyplace that explained this part. Do I write a function and `return` that response value? Or use `print`? Or should I use `sys.stdout.write()`? I am a novice at this and I don't understand how this works. A lot of questions here showed `json` being used. Should I use it? And can you explain why it is needed?(I'm a beginner, sorry if this sounds stupid)
2. Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

The code looks like this:

```
myprog.py

from string import Template
import webbrowser

template1 = Template(
"""
<html>
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "\javascript\prototype.js">
    </script>
    <script>

    function displayResults()
    {
        new Ajax.Updater("response", "\display.py");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td id = "myid" onclick = displayResults()> $something</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p id = "response">replace this</p>
</body>
</html>
""")

d = template1.substitute(something = nothing)
f= open('filename.html','w')
f.write(d)
f.close()
webbrowser.open_new('filename.html')
```

My python file `display.py` looks like this

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Content-type: text/html")
response = "dadada"
sys.stdout.write(response)
sys.stdout.write("</br>")
```

My platform is windows. I am using the new version of Prototype(1.7.1).

Thanks

Megh

Answer (score 1):

You need to write line separators after your headers:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
response = "dadada"
sys.stdout.write(response)
sys.stdout.write("</br>")
```

You can use `print`; it'll add line separators for you:

```
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
response = "dadada"
print response + '</br>'
```

If you are not married to CGI scripts, give micro-web frameworks like Flask, Bottle or Pyramid  a try instead; these take care of most of the HTTP details for you.

Comment: I am using `print` now but still nothing happens when I click. I haven't stored `display.py` in `\www\cgi-bin\` according to the [tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm). Does that have any effect? Should I make some config files for this to work?

Comment: Can you reach the `/display.py` URL in your browser? What happens?

Comment: Yes, I can reach it. The browser displays the contents of the .py file.

Comment: Now, When I run my program and click event occurs, the old content disappears, but no `"dadada"` is being displayed in its place.

Comment: The CGI is not executed; make sure the executable flag is set.